# How to auto switch videoview to fullscreen mode in android?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have an activity with an actionbar and a videoview.How i can set the videoview to fullscreen mode and hide the actionbar after user inactive for a time.And when user tap on screen the actionbar show again and videoview switch to normal mode.
Thank all .

Comment: put a timer after user touch and simply call 'getActionBar().hide()' after time is over.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set your own [mediacontroller.mediaplayercontrol](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.MediaPlayerControl.html) and override pause and start.
You Also
Started going to do **getSupportActionBar().hide();** to play video.
Finished video will run the following code.
You can also use this form.

```
myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer vmp) {
        getSupportActionBar().show();
    }
});
```